# Asset pipeline best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Is it best practice to have one manifest for a whole application (which loads the css/js for all pages), or a manifest for each controller so it only loads what's needed, or ... ?

The docs mention the idea of just including the css for that particular controllers stylesheet (such as stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller), but that assumes you have zero common styles. And it's obviously not necessary to load styles that are specific to 10 other controllers.

So it feels that creating a manifest for each controller might be the way to go? It would generally include a 'common' stylesheet, plus that controllers specific stylesheet.

What's the best practice here?